# Convert GPS to RD (Dutch) coordinates

Tags: ios, gps, swift2, mapkit, coordinates

I can't figure out how to convert GPS coordinates to Dutch RD coordinates using Swift 2 and MapKit.
I search the web for formulas that I can write in Swift to make the converting, but no success.
Did anyone have this problem solved, I will be glad if anyone can help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will most probably not find swift code for that task.
But you can call C libraries from Swift.
There are some universal geographical conversion libs, written in C.

To call statically linked C libraries, read further here:
https://tetontech.wordpress.com/2014/07/03/swift-and-statically-linking-c-libraries/

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, hope will be useful for someone. Can be test it here
http://www.gpscoordinates.eu/convert-rd-coordinates.php

```
extension CollectionType {
    subscript (safe index: Index) -> Generator.Element? {
    return indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
}


func gpsToRd(lat: Double, lon: Double) -> (lat: Double, lng: Double) {
    let referenceRdX = 155000.0
    let referenceRdY = 463000.0
    let referenceWgs84X = 52.15517440
    let referenceWgs84Y = 5.38720621

    let Rpq: [[Double]] = [[0.0, 190094.945, -0.008, -32.391, 0.0], [-0.705, -11832.228, 0.0, -0.608, 0.0], [0.0, -114.221, 0.0, 0.148, 0.0], [0.0, -2.340, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]

    let Spq: [[Double]] = [[0.0, 0.433, 3638.893, 0.0, 0.092], [309056.544, -0.032, -157.984, 0.0, -0.054], [73.077, 0.0, -6.439, 0.0, 0.0], [59.788, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]


    let d_lattitude = (0.36 * (lat - referenceWgs84X))
    let d_longitude = (0.36 * (lon - referenceWgs84Y))

    var calc_latt = 0.0
    var calc_long = 0.0

    for p in 0...3  {
        for q in 0...4  {
            if let _Rpq = Rpq[p][safe: q] {
                calc_latt += _Rpq * pow(d_lattitude, Double(p)) * pow(d_longitude, Double(q))
            }
            if let _Spq = Spq[p][safe: q] {
                calc_long += _Spq * pow(d_lattitude, Double(p)) * pow(d_longitude, Double(q));
            }
        }
    }

    let rd_x_coordinate = referenceRdX + calc_latt
    let rd_y_coordinate = referenceRdY + calc_long

    return (rd_x_coordinate, rd_y_coordinate)
}
```